# Camera mobile used for progressive web app

Tags: vue.js

I realize a progressive application web app under view and I have a problem for the use of the mobile camera. I have a blank page. Here is my file seen for the camera:

```
    <template>
  <div class="container" id="app">
    <router-link class="waves-effect waves-light btn" to="/livreur" @click.native="hideMenu"><i class="material-icons">arrow_back</i>
    </router-link>
    <div class="camera-modal">
      <video ref="video" class="camera-stream"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  var constraints = {
    audio: false,
    video: {
      facingMode: {exact: 'environment'}
    }
  }

  export default {
    mounted () {
      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
        .then(function (mediaStream) {
          var video = document.querySelector('video')
          video.srcObject = mediaStream
          video.onloadedmetadata = function (e) {
            video.play()
          }
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          console.log(err.name + ': ' + err.message)
        })
    }
  }
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style>

</style>
```

My file main.js:

```
// The Vue build version to load with the `import` command
// (runtime-only or standalone) has been set in webpack.base.conf with an alias.
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import Axios from 'axios'
import VueSignature from 'vue-signature-pad'

Vue.prototype.$http = Axios

const token = localStorage.getItem('user-token')
if (token) {
  Vue.prototype.$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token
}

Vue.use(VueSignature)
Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

My router.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import store from './store.js'
import Home from '@/components/Home'
import Delivered from '@/components/Delivered'
import Absent from '@/components/Absent'
import Refused from '@/components/Refused'
import Livreur from '@/components/preprations/Livreur'
import Prepa from '@/components/preprations/Prepa'
import Scan from '@/components/preprations/Scan'
import Login from '@/components/Login'

Vue.use(Router)

let router = new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'Login',
      component: Login
    },
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/delivered',
      name: 'delivered',
      component: Delivered
    },
    {
      path: '/absent',
      name: 'absent',
      component: Absent
    },
    {
      path: '/refused',
      name: 'refused',
      component: Refused
    },
    {
      path: '/livreur',
      name: 'livreur',
      component: Livreur
    },
    {
      path: '/prepa',
      name: 'prepa',
      component: Prepa
    },
    {
      path: '/scan',
      name: 'Scan',
      component: Scan
    }
  ]
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    if (store.getters.isLoggedIn) {
      next()
      return
    }
    next('/login')
  } else {
    next()
  }
})

export default router
```

I tried to change the constraints but nothing helps, I try the default values ​​but it does not work.

I do not see where it's blocking at all. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Blank page probably means a useful error in the developer console.

Comment: No error in console just NotFoundError: Requested device not found but because I do not have a camera. I can not see the errors on my mobile.

Comment: Android and iOS both offer a remote debugger for viewing errors on the device itself.